# P5.js does not clear the canvas automatically

Tags: javascript, canvas, processing, p5.js

In P5.js, Somehow, when I'm drawing any shape and moving it, the shape leaves sort of like a trail.

Tried with an ellipse[image]

Testing code:

```
function draw() {
    if (times < 100) {
        fill(255);
        ellipse(times, times, 10, 10);
        times++
    }
}
```

I tried adding `erase()` and it does seem to do the trick coupled with re-rendering the background, but it would clear the canvas at each frame which is not what I want.

Comment: It will be clearer for us if you say exactly what you want.

Comment: @GabrielLupu Oh sorry it was my first question and I thought I'd be clear, I'll try to be more descriptive from next time, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call [`background()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/background) to clear the canvas. `background()` fills the entire canvas with the specified color.

For instance:

```js
function draw() {
    if (times < 100) {

        background(255, 255, 255);

        fill(255);
        ellipse(times, times, 10, 10);
        times++
    }
}
```